# Integer.parseInt giving java.lang.NumberFormatException in Java

Tags: java

I have a character array as

```
char[] bitsString = new char[16];
bitsString = {'1','1','1','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','0'};
```

Then I converted it to the corresponding integer as follows:

```
int givenNumber = Integer.parseInt(new String(bitsString), 2);
```

The above logic works fine when number bitstring array length is less than 10. But when it is increased to 11 or more, it is showing me  `java.lang.NumberFormatException` **why** ?

Comment: This compiles fine on my computer. The output is 64998.

Comment: Presumably it throws that exception when you provide an invalid input of some kind; since you have provided valid input here we cannot tell you **how** *or* **why** the *unspecified* input throws the exception.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you're forgetting to pass the 2. Integer.MAX_VALUE is a 10-digit number.

Answer (score 2):

After some hit and trials I found that, it was the case since the 16 bit value is crossing the `Integer` limit.

But when it is changed from `int` to `long`

```
long givenNumber = Long.parseLong(new String(bitsString), 2);
```

it is working perfectly fine. Since in this case long has 64 bits length.

Comment: An integer is 32 bits long in Java.